# What are the flag impacts for individual flags?

Tags: support, flags

I know that every flag has different impact. For example, the close votes are put into the review queue instead of going directly to the moderator, and **in need of mod intervention** does go to the moderator. Spam or **Rude or Offensive** seem like the heaviest since they have a red background around the text in my profile flags

How are each of the individual flags treated by users, and the Community bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the flags that I do know of:

- Spam flags

Posts with spam flags are sent to the review queue for further evaluation and possible deletion by moderators. These posts must be taken care of immediately and might be auto-deleted if enough spam flags are collected. Sometimes, they will be used as review audits to make sure users are people with sense, not spammy robots. Spam flags cast an automatic downvote on the said post. Having a post with six spam flags will result in a rep deduction of 100 and the user might be suspended and/or account deletion (and possibly with all other associated accounts aka sock accounts).

> > The spam and abusive flags are designed to automatically eliminate truly disruptive posts through the collaboration of the community.
>
> - 3 flags -- post is banished from the front page.
> - 6 flags -- post is locked, deleted, and the owner loses 100 reputation.

---

- Rude or Offensive flags

Posts with these flags will go to the moderators for further evaluation and possible deletion. Users who have been posting posts that receives too many of these flags may receive suspension. Flags like these will behave like spam flags: 3+ flags means removal from front pages (question only) and 6 flags means auto-lock, deletion, and a rep deduction of 100 rep. The user at question can face serious consequences and can be suspended and/or account removed.

> The spam and abusive flags are designed to automatically eliminate truly disruptive posts through the collaboration of the community.
>
> - 3 flags -- post is banished from the front page.
> - 6 flags -- post is locked, deleted, and the owner loses 100 reputation.

---

- In need of moderator attention flags

These posts will be dealt with by the moderators themselves. Action can be taken and severe consequences may arise, depending on the severity of the flag and actions. Flags like these will be taken very seriously unless they are used unnecessarily.

> You'll be required to enter a comment clearly explaining what the problem is. After that, these moderator flags go in a special high priority queue visible to all moderators. (Users with the Moderator Tools privilege cannot view these flags.) We take moderator flags quite seriously; rest assured that they are all followed up on!

---

- Should be closed (question only)

  - Duplicate
  - Off-topic
  - Unclear what you are asking about
  - Too broad
  - Primarily opinion-based

If any of these flags are used, the question will be sent to the Close Votes review queue to for further evaluation and possible closure of the question. Closed questions will count against the users and may bring in an automatic question ban and failure to get [Curious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/242/curious), [Inquisitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/243/inquisitive), and [Socratic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic).

---

- Not an answer (answer only)

Answers flagged for this reason will be sent to review queue for further evaluation and possible action, including removal of the answer. These answers can go against the user and might raise an automatic answer ban.

---

- Very low quality

Posts flagged for this reason will be sent to the VLQ queue for further evaluation and possible deletion.

---

- Comment flags

Comments are not sent to the review queue unlike flagged posts. They are dealt separately and may cause the deletion of a comment.

> In addition to bringing the comment to the attention of the moderators, a sufficient number of flags on a single comment will cause it to be deleted automatically. The number of flags required for deletion varies based on the number of votes on the comment, as well as the content of the comment itself.

---

Information has been found through experience, remembering past posts relating to this and this [Help Center link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: Spam and offensive flags are only surfaced to moderators; the 10k flag queue was dismantled long ago.

Comment: "auto-deleted" and "self-deleted" are two different things; spam-flagged posts get auto-deleted. And the bit about "legal" action seems somewhat absurd - say what you actually mean..